# function not defined when I try to create an object and call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an object and then call initialize function on that object. However I get initialize not defined. This is my code:

```
var SomeJSObj = function () {
    function Initialize() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    };
};
```

when I create a new object of `SomeJSObj` and call `Initialize` I get function not defined. Could anybody please help me track the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Initialize` is currently not accessible outside of the `SomeJSObj` constructor. You need to expose it, either on each instance or on the prototype:

```
var SomeJSObj = function () {
    this.Initialize = function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    };
};
```

On the prototype is more efficient, since only one copy of the function has to exist in memory, instead of one for each instance:

```
var SomeJSObj = function () {};
SomeJSObj.prototype.Initialize = function () {
    //Do stuff
};
```

Comment: Thanks James for explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this since you want to make the `Initialize` function public:

```
var SomeJSObj = function () {
    this.Initialize = function() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    }
};

var t = new SomeJSObj();
t.Initialize();​
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `$(document).ready` should be *outside* the function definitions:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

The problem is that your methods should be defined on the object using the prefix `this.`:

```
this.Initialize = function() {
    ...
};
```

So all in all it comes to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var SomeJSObj = function () {

        this.Initialize = function() {
             alert('hello');
        };

    };

});
```

And to call your methods you must create an instance:

```
var instance = new SomeJSObj(); // make sure this in in $(document).ready
```

and call the method:

```
instance.initialize(); // works
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, Simple and easy way.

```
var SomeJSObj = function () {
    this.Initialize=function() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    };

};

var x = new SomeJSObj();
x.Initialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7qfm/).

```
var SomeJSObj = function () {
    this.initialize();
};
SomeJSObj.prototype.initialize = function() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
      alert('hello');
  });
};
new ​SomeJSObj​();​
```